# Mysql timestamp issue

Tags: 16.04, mysql, php, nginx

I have a PHP/Laravel application running on a Digitalocean droplet.  The droplet resides in one of their San Francisco data centers, but I have the Ubuntu timezone set to Etc/UTC.  Problem I'm having is Mysql is timestamping records at America/Los_Angeles time.  I want records to be at UTC and then convert the times to local timezone in my views using Carbon.

nginx is set to UTC
php.ini is set to UTC
mysql global and session time_zones are set to SYSTEM

Ubuntu 16.04, NGINX, PHP, Mysql, Laravel 5.3

Any ideas?

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10686965/1810128) ?

Comment: There's a lot within that thread, but I went through it all and nothing helped.  I ran this... 

mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone, @@global.system_time_zone;

and that gave me... 

SYSTEM | SYSTEM | UTC